# Is it necessary to format peripheral storage which may have been connected while the machine was infected with a virus?

Tags: windows-7, virus, malware

My mother’s desktop was infected by a virus today. I have reinstalled Windows, but I am wondering if it’s unsafe to leave her storage drives (and external drives).

She has a lot of important data and photos on them, not all of which is backed up, so I would like to leave the drives in tact if possible.

Thoughts?

Comment: You need to scan it for viruses.  Use multiple scans malwarebytes,avira, and whatever else you can get your hands on.

Comment: Would also recommend downloading a boot cd virus scanner from one of the more well know vendors ... Aviara , etc... The whole problem with scanning from the pc that was infected.. if you missed any part of the infection, and it re-activates, then your scanning from a machine that is trying to hide its actions, and it could alter files on the removable storage.  But if you boot an OS from CD, its less likely an infected file could be loaded into memory, unless it was a bios infection (very uncommon)

Comment: As others have recommended, only scanning with an AV is required. I suggest [herdProtect](http://www.herdprotect.com/) which uses the combined power of 68 antivirus engines. Kind of like Virus-total, but installed on your computer.